# First Come First Serve Algorithm Implementation

Tags: java, cpu

This is a project given to us by our professor.

The requirements are to implement 3 pre-picked algorithms of CPU Scheduling in JAVA.
our group was given FCFS(First Come First Serve),Round Robin,and MFQ(Multi-feedback Queue) algorithms.

now i had made this FCFS code:

```
import java.util.Vector;


public class FCFS
{
    protected int[] arrivalTime;
    protected int[] burstTime;
    protected int[] job;
    protected int[] jobIdle;
    protected int numberOfProcess;
    protected int[] waitingTime;
    protected int[] finishedTime;
    protected int averageWT,averageTTsum;
    protected int jobs;

    public FCFS (int[] aT,int[] bT,int[] job,int num)
    {
        arrivalTime = aT;
        burstTime = bT;
        this.job = job;
        numberOfProcess = num;
        waitingTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
        finishedTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
        jobs = 0;
    }

public void FCFS()
{
    int firstCome,tempArrivalTime,tempBurst;
 //sort processes 
    for (int i = 0; i < (numberOfProcess - 1); i++) 
    {
   for (int j = (i + 1); j < numberOfProcess; j++)
   {
        if (arrivalTime[j] < arrivalTime[i]) 
        {

            firstCome = job[j];
            job[j] = job[i];
            job[i] = firstCome;
            tempArrivalTime = arrivalTime[j];
            arrivalTime[j] = arrivalTime[i];
            arrivalTime[i] = tempArrivalTime;
            tempBurst = burstTime[j];
            burstTime[j] = burstTime[i];
            burstTime[i] = tempBurst;

                }

        }

    }

    System.out.println("\n==Displaying Table of Jobs Sorted According to Arrival Time==");
    displaySorted();  
    System.out.println("======DISPLAYING GANTT CHART======");
    solveWaitingTime();
    solveAverageTime();


}
public void solveAverageTime()
{
    //ATT
    for(int i = 0;i<numberOfProcess;i++)
    averageTTsum = averageTTsum+(finishedTime[i]-arrivalTime[i]);
    //AWT
    for(int j=0;j<numberOfProcess;j++)
        averageWT = averageWT+(waitingTime[j] - arrivalTime[j]);


    double aTT = (float)averageTTsum/numberOfProcess;
    double aWT=(float)averageWT/numberOfProcess;
    System.out.format("ATT: %.2f ",aTT);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.format("AWT: %.2f ",aWT);
}

public void solveWaitingTime()
{   int ctr=0;
    Vector<Integer> idleWT = new Vector<Integer>();
    Vector<Boolean> idle = new Vector<Boolean>();
    for(int z = 0; z < numberOfProcess; z++)  //run through all processes
    {
        if(ctr > arrivalTime[z])                        //if counter is greater than the arrival time
        {idle.add(Boolean.TRUE);                           //an idle time is not needed hence TRUE
            for(int k = 0; k < burstTime[z]; k++)       //do burst time of current process
            {

            ctr++;                              

                }
            jobs++;

        } 
        else                                        //if counter is less than arrival time
        {
            while(ctr <= arrivalTime[z]) 
            {
                if(ctr == arrivalTime[z])                   //if counter is equal to arrivalTime
                {
                   jobs++;                                  
                    for(int j = arrivalTime[z]; j < (arrivalTime[z] + burstTime[z]); j++)//starting from arrival time
                        {                                                               //do the burst time of process
                            ctr++;

                        }
                    idle.add(Boolean.TRUE);             
                } 
                else                                    //if not equal to arrival time
                {
                    jobs++;             
                ctr++;                                     //an idle time will be consumed
                    idle.add(Boolean.FALSE);                //idle has been detected
                }

            }

            }

        finishedTime[z] = ctr;                  //turn-around time is = to total counter
        if(z==0)                                //if time is 0
       idleWT.add(0);                           //IdlewaitingTime of first process is 0
        else idleWT.add(ctr);                   //else ctr
}
     waitingTime[0] = 0;
    for(int z = 1;z<numberOfProcess;z++)
    {  
        waitingTime[z] = finishedTime[z] - burstTime[z];//compute waiting time

    }

//debugging purposes
  /* for(int i = 0;i<numberOfProcess;i++)
    {   System.out.print("arrival: "+arrivalTime[i]);
        System.out.print("burst: "+burstTime[i]);
        System.out.print("wait: "+waitingTime[i]);
        System.out.print("finished: "+finishedTime[i]);

    }*/
   System.out.println(""+idleWT.toString());               //debugging purposes
       System.out.println(""+idle.toString());  //debugging purposes
       System.out.println("Jobs: "+jobs);   //debugging purposes
       int ctr2 = 0;

    for(int y = 0; y < numberOfProcess; y++)        //displays gannt Chart
        {
            if(idle.elementAt(ctr2)==false)                         //if an idle time is detected
            {   if(ctr2==0) 
            {System.out.print("|I"+(waitingTime[y+1])+" |"); ctr2++;}   //print an I to symbolize idle time and its burst time
            else {
                System.out.print("|I "+(idleWT.elementAt(y)-waitingTime[y])+" |");
                ctr2++;
            }

            }
            System.out.print("|P"+job[y]+"("+burstTime[y]+")"+" |");            //else print name of processes
            ctr2++;
        }   
    System.out.println("");
    //gantt chart time display
    for(int x = 0;x<numberOfProcess;x++)
    {  if(idleWT.elementAt(x) == 0)
        System.out.print(""+waitingTime[x]);
    else System.out.print("      "+waitingTime[x]+ "      "+idleWT.elementAt(x));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public void displaySorted()
{
    System.out.println("\n------------------------------------");

  System.out.println("Process | Arrival Time | CPU Burst ");


    for(int y = 0; y < numberOfProcess; y++) 
        {
            System.out.println("P" + job[y] + "\t\t"
            + arrivalTime[y] +"\t      " 
            + burstTime[y]);

        }

  System.out.println("------------------------------------\n");
   }

 }
```

The supposed output is like this:

```
Enter Number of processes: 5 //sample only
Enter Arrival time of p1:
Enter Burst Time of p1:
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Enter Arrival time of p5:
Enter Burst Time of p5:
==Displaying Table of Jobs Sorted According to Arrival Time==

------------------------------------
Process | Arrival Time | CPU Burst 

p1
p2
p3
p4
p5

======DISPLAYING GANTT CHART======
   p1(burst)  | p2(burst2)   | .....
0        burst|        burst2| .....

AWT:
ATT:
```

now i'm having problems in my code and may have overlooked too much to see the problem and these are:

1. It doesn't record the correct burst-time of the idle time
2. It doesn't display right amount of idle times in gannt chart
3. I think there will be an input that would totally mess up my program.
4. Also i have declared some variables that at first i thought i can use but then i change my mind and decided to not use them.
5. I also think there are flaws in my logic for this algorithm please point them out,it will help me greatly in school.

How do I solve for these problems??
I hope I have provided enough info.

Comment: your code is way too messy. i'm guessing there might be some mistake in handling the array indexes? you might want to consider doing some refactoring (say, introduce a Job, JobStatistics and a CPU class to help calculate your time slices); perhaps it might help you spot your bugs.

Comment: In addition to what @happymeal said, the foundation of a FCFS system is a simple queue of processes.  Unless instructed otherwise by your professor, you should be using more appropriate data structures to handle the queuing and dequeuing of processes (jobs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FCFS_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //----------------------------------------Reading I/O File--------------------------------------
            string s = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();   // returns the directory of the exe file
            if (File.Exists(s + @"\input.txt")) //checking if the input files exists
                Console.WriteLine("File Exists");
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
                Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________________________");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________________________");
            //----------------------------------------Data Into List--------------------------------------
            string FileText = File.ReadAllText(s + @"\input.txt"); //reading all the text in the input file
            string[] lines = FileText.Split('\n'); //splitting the lines
            List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] tabs = lines[i].Split('\t');//splitting the tabs to get objects' variables
                Process x = new Process(tabs[0], int.Parse(tabs[1]), int.Parse(tabs[2]), int.Parse(tabs[3]));//creating object
                processes.Add(x);//adding object to the list
            }
            //   ----------------------------------------Sorting The List--------------------------------------
            Process temp;
            for (int k = 0; k < processes.Count; k++)
            {
                for (int i = k + 1; i < processes.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (processes[k].arrivalTime > processes[i].arrivalTime || (processes[k].arrivalTime == processes[i].arrivalTime && processes[k].brust > processes[i].brust))
                    {
                        temp = processes[i];
                        processes[i] = processes[k];
                        processes[k] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Processes After Sorting");
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("Name\tArrival\tBrust\tPriority");
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(processes[i].name + "\t" + processes[i].arrivalTime + "\t" + processes[i].brust + "\t" + processes[i].priority);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________________________");
            //----------------------------------------Gantt Chart--------------------------------------
            Console.WriteLine("Gantt Chart");
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________________________");
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(processes[i].name + "\t");
                if (processes[i].arrivalTime < counter)
                    printSpaces(counter);
                else
                {
                    printSpaces(processes[i].arrivalTime);
                    counter = processes[i].arrivalTime;
                }
                printHashes(processes[i].brust);
                counter += processes[i].brust;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________________________");
            //-----------------------------------Completing Data And final Table-------------------------
            int clock = 0, totalwait = 0, totalturnAround = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (processes[i].arrivalTime > clock)
                {
                    processes[i].start = processes[i].arrivalTime;
                    clock += processes[i].start - processes[i].arrivalTime;
                    clock += processes[i].brust;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                        processes[i].start = processes[i - 1].end;
                    clock += processes[i].brust;
                }
                if (processes[i].start > processes[i].arrivalTime)
                    processes[i].wait = processes[i].start - processes[i].arrivalTime;
                else processes[i].wait = 0;
                processes[i].end = processes[i].start + processes[i].brust;
                processes[i].turnAround = processes[i].wait + processes[i].brust;
                totalwait += processes[i].wait;
                totalturnAround += processes[i].turnAround;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Name\tArrival\tBrust\tStart\tEnd\tWait\tturnaround");
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(processes[i].name + "\t" + processes[i].arrivalTime + "\t" + processes[i].brust + "\t" + processes[i].start + "\t" + processes[i].end + "\t" + processes[i].wait + "\t" + processes[i].turnAround);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            double att = 0, awt = 0;
            awt = (double)totalwait / (double)processes.Count;
            att = (double)totalturnAround / (double)processes.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("A.W.T= " + awt + "\t A.T.T= " + att);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void printSpaces(int counter)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
        public static void printHashes(int brust)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < brust; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }
        }

    }
}


class Process
{
    public Process(string name, int arrivalTime, int brust, int priority)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        this.brust = brust;
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    public Process()
    {

    }
    public string name;
    public int arrivalTime;
    public int brust;
    public int priority;
    public int wait;
    public int end;
    public int start;
    public int turnAround;
}
```